# MVC / HTML.DropDownListFor / making default option and its value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, html-helper

I have `CreateForm` action in **ProductController**. This action uses view with model: `ProductSupplierViewModel` (consists of Product and List<Supplier> *Suppliers*).

In my CSHTML i have

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Product.Supplier)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Product.Supplier.Id, new SelectList(Model.Suppliers, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

BUT, this way i only have my default option set to blank (by using two quotation makrs in html helper).

**What i need to know is:**

1. how to set a `value="0"` to that blank option?
2. Does the web have *default value* if we dont specify one for it or?

Trying to get 0 because in my **DataAccessLayer** i have `CreateProduct(Product p)` method where i'll specify:

```
if(p.Supplier.Id == 0) // from parameter
{ 
  *put NULL value in this DB field*
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple is:

```asp
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Product.Supplier.Id, 
    new SelectList(Model.Suppliers, "Id", "Name", 0),
    "Please Select...",
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This creates a default item "Please Select...". However it's mandatory to select an item different than the default.

If selecting an item is not mandatory, you can do:

**Controller**

```cs
model.Suppliers.Insert(0, new Supplier()
{
    Id = 0,
    Name = "Please Select..."
});
```

**View**

```asp
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Product.Supplier.Id, 
    new SelectList(Model.Suppliers, "Id", "Name", 0), 
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```